# issue with slide change using translateX and screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with changing the images in my slider. The slider is 100% width of the screen, and I tried to set the screen width with px and % to calculate the translateX, but with the same resault as you can see on the image.

Do you have any other ideas what I can do to make my slider work, or where I've made a mistake?

[image]

```js
const left = document.querySelector(".header-slider__left");
const right = document.querySelector(".header-slider__right");
const frame = document.querySelector(".header-slider__frame");
const slider = document.querySelector(".header-slider__carousel");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".header-slider__item");
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".header-slider__img");
const bottom = document.querySelector(".header-slider__bottom");

// Getting initial viewport size
let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

// Getting new viewport size after change in viewport size
function handleViewportResize() {
    let newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    viewportWidth = newWidth;
}

// This event will trigger when viewport size changes
window.addEventListener("resize", handleViewportResize);

// slider frame size for different devices
const tabletScreen = 500;
const mobileScreen = 300;
const laptopScreen = 100;

let playing = true;
let slideNumber = 1;
const length = slides.length;

// creating rounded circles dynamically relevant to number of images in slider, and adding them to DOM
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "button";
    bottom.appendChild(div);
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
//setting first rounded circle background white, when website loaded for the very firstime
buttons[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";

// setting all rounded circles background color to transparent
const resetBg = () => {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    });
};

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        resetBg();
        //Setting slider movement for different devices when user click on rounded circles
        if (viewportWidth <= 480) {
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${i * mobileScreen}px)`;
        } else if (viewportWidth <= 768) {
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${i * tabletScreen}px)`;
        } else {
            slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${i * laptopScreen}%)`;
            console.log(i * laptopScreen);
        }
        slideNumber = i + 1;
        button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
});

// This function will trigger the slider to the next slide
const nextSlide = () => {
    if (viewportWidth <= 480) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideNumber * mobileScreen}px)`;
    } else if (viewportWidth <= 768) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideNumber * tabletScreen}px)`;
    } else {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideNumber * laptopScreen}%)`;
    }
    console.log(slides.length);
    console.log(images.length);
    console.log(viewportWidth);
    slideNumber++;
};

// This function will trigger the slider to the previous slide
const prevSlide = () => {
    if (viewportWidth <= 480) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(slideNumber - 2) * mobileScreen}px)`;
    } else if (viewportWidth <= 768) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(slideNumber - 2) * tabletScreen}px)`;
    } else {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(slideNumber - 2) * laptopScreen}%)`;
    }

    slideNumber--;
};

// This function will trigger the slider to the first slide
const getFirstSlide = () => {
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
    slideNumber = 1;
};

// This function will trigger the slider to the last slide
const getLastSlide = () => {
    if (viewportWidth <= 480) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(length - 1) * mobileScreen}px)`;
    } else if (viewportWidth <= 768) {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(length - 1) * tabletScreen}px)`;
    } else {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${(length - 1) * laptopScreen}%)`;
    }

    slideNumber = length;
};

const changeColor = () => {
    resetBg();
    buttons[slideNumber - 1].style.backgroundColor = "white";
};

// Move to next slide
const moveToNext = () => {
    slideNumber < length ? nextSlide() : getFirstSlide();
    changeColor();
};

//Autoplay slider on website loading
let autoplayInterval = setInterval(function () {
    moveToNext();
}, 4000); // Do this every 4 second, increase this!

// Stop Slider when mouseover
slider.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    clearInterval(autoplayInterval);
});

// Continue slider when mouseout
slider.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    if (playing) {
        autoplayInterval = setInterval(function () {
            moveToNext();
        }, 4000);
    }
});

// Move to previous slide
const moveToPrevious = () => {
    slideNumber > 1 ? prevSlide() : getLastSlide();
    changeColor();
};

// When right arrow icon is clicked
right.addEventListener("click", () => {
    moveToNext();
});

// When left arrow icon is clicked
left.addEventListener("click", () => {
    moveToPrevious();
});

// Slider Work with Keyboard 'Left Arrow' and 'Right Arrow' keys
slider.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowLeft": // left arrow key
            moveToPrevious();
            break;
        case "ArrowRight": // right arrow key
            moveToNext();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
});

// Give it keyboard focus
slider.focus();
```

```css
.header-slider {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.875rem;
  position: relative;
}
.header-slider__carousel {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.header-slider__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.header-slider__top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.header-slider__frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-slider__carousel {
  display: flex;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.header-slider__item {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .header-slider__item {
    height: 940px;
  }
}
.header-slider__bottom {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.875rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  /* move the button to the center horizontally */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  bottom: 0.625rem;
  z-index: 5;
}
.header-slider .button {
  width: 0.938rem;
  height: 0.938rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-slider__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .header-slider__overlay {
    height: 940px;
  }
}
.header-slider__img img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .header-slider__img img {
    height: 940px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header__slider header-slider">
        
        <div class="header-slider__wrapper">
           
            <div class="header-slider__top">
                
            <img src="" class="header-slider__left" alt="" />
                
                <div class="header-slider__frame">
                    
                    <ul class="header-slider__carousel">
                        <li class="header-slider__item">
                           <div class="header-slider__overlay"></div>
                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4254553/pexels-photo-4254553.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1900"  class="header-slider__img"/>';
                        </li>';                          
<li class="header-slider__item">
                           <div class="header-slider__overlay"></div>
                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4145354/pexels-photo-4145354.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1900"  class="header-slider__img"/>';
                        </li>';    
                         
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <img src="" class="header-slider__right" alt="" />

            </div>

            <div class="header-slider__bottom"></div>
            
        </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's word chowder now. Also, please replace your SCSS with compiled CSS and your WordPress markup with sample rendered HTML so we can see this in action.